Python investing.com historical stock data by curl request
How to force the server to send me the query data by curl in Python directly from the url_historical_data page as shown in the example. I have already tried different things, but I must do something wrong when passing the query parameters. I can't figure it out. Running Windows curl on a 64 bit PC. Please help?
from subprocess import run, PIPE
from htmlement import HTMLement
from json import dumps


def get_data(tabel):
    try:
        thead = tabel.find("thead")
        trh = thead.find("tr")
        header = []
        cnt = 0
        for th in trh:
            tmp = th.find('div').find('button').find('span')
            header.append(tmp.text)
            cnt += 1
        print(header)

        body = tabel.find("tbody")
        for tr in body.findall("tr"):
            row = []
            cnt = 0
            for td in tr:
                if cnt == 0:
                    tijd = td.find('time')
                    row = [tijd.text]
                else:
                    row.append(td.text)
                cnt += 1
            print(row)

    except:
        print('table ; data ; invalid')
    return


def get_document(val):
    url = f'https://www.investing.com{val}-historical-data'
    print('url:', url)
    params = {"from_date": "07/01/2024", "to_date": "08/31/2024", "interval": "Daily"}
    cnfg = ['curl.exe', '-s', '-A ' + 'Chrome/91.0.4472.114', '-H Content-Type: application/json', '-d ' + dumps(params), url]
    print('config:', cnfg, chr(10))

    htm_doc = run(cnfg, stdout=PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
    try:
        parser = HTMLement("table", attrs={"class": "freeze-column-w-1 w-full overflow-x-auto text-xs leading-4"})
        parser.feed(htm_doc)
        table = parser.close()
        get_data(table)
    except:
        print('html ; table ; invalid')
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_document('/equities/aarons')
    exit()
    

The above python script will return the default page output instead of returning the data corresponding the query parameters:
url: https://www.investing.com/equities/aarons-historical-data
config: ['curl.exe', '-s', '-A Chrome/91.0.4472.114', '-H Content-Type: application/json', "-d {'st_date': '07/01/2024', 'end_date': '08/31/2024', 'interval_sec': 'Daily', 'action': 'historical_data'}", 'https://www.investing.com/equities/aarons-historical-data']

['Date', 'Price', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Vol.', 'Change %']
['Sep 03, 2024', '10.00', '9.97', '10.08', '9.83', '2.96M', '-0.89%']
['Aug 30, 2024', '10.09', '10.09', '10.10', '10.09', '257.67K', '0.00%']
['Aug 29, 2024', '10.09', '10.10', '10.10', '10.09', '237.03K', '0.00%']
['Aug 28, 2024', '10.09', '10.09', '10.11', '10.08', '729.33K', '+0.20%']
['Aug 27, 2024', '10.07', '10.08', '10.09', '10.07', '313.87K', '-0.10%']
['Aug 26, 2024', '10.08', '10.09', '10.10', '10.08', '349.82K', '+0.10%']
['Aug 23, 2024', '10.07', '10.09', '10.11', '10.07', '879.99K', '0.00%']
['Aug 22, 2024', '10.07', '10.08', '10.10', '10.07', '599.27K', '-0.20%']
['Aug 21, 2024', '10.09', '10.09', '10.10', '10.08', '376.91K', '+0.10%']
['Aug 20, 2024', '10.08', '10.09', '10.09', '10.08', '484.85K', '0.00%']
['Aug 19, 2024', '10.08', '10.08', '10.10', '10.07', '1.04M', '+0.10%']
['Aug 16, 2024', '10.07', '10.08', '10.09', '10.07', '827.66K', '-0.10%']
['Aug 15, 2024', '10.08', '10.08', '10.09', '10.06', '776.58K', '+0.20%']
['Aug 14, 2024', '10.06', '10.08', '10.10', '10.06', '655.35K', '0.00%']
['Aug 13, 2024', '10.06', '10.04', '10.10', '10.04', '1.39M', '+0.50%']
['Aug 12, 2024', '10.01', '10.03', '10.04', '10.01', '463.42K', '-0.10%']
['Aug 09, 2024', '10.02', '10.01', '10.02', '10.00', '738.52K', '0.00%']
['Aug 08, 2024', '10.02', '10.04', '10.04', '10.00', '214.86K', '+0.20%']
['Aug 07, 2024', '10.00', '10.00', '10.06', '9.99', '590.25K', '-0.40%']
['Aug 06, 2024', '10.04', '9.96', '10.09', '9.95', '747.36K', '+0.70%']
['Aug 05, 2024', '9.97', '9.96', '10.02', '9.95', '1.23M', '-0.60%']

Process finished with exit code 0


If you inspect the response you will notice that the page is driven primarily by Javascript. You'll neeed to use something like selenium to get what you want

Investing.com does not allow screen scraping. "The Services may not be used or accessed by any automated machine, bot, spider, or such other automated feature or service;" ( https://www.investing.com/about-us/terms-and-conditions ).  You can use the API instead.

You can get the data as JSON from the API:
import subprocess
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def get_data(stock_id):
    url = f'https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/historical/{stock_id}' 
    params = {
        'start-date': '2024-07-01',
        'end-date': '2024-08-31',
        'time-frame': 'Daily',
        'add-missing-rows': 'false'
    }

    cnfg = ['curl', '-A', 'Chrome/128.0.0.0', '-H', 'domain-id: www', '-G', url, '-d', urlencode(params)]

    output = subprocess.run(cnfg, capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
    return json.loads(output)


data = get_data('39136')
print(data)


Or you can use curl_cffi which supports http2:
pip install curl_cffi --upgrade

It works just like requests:
from curl_cffi import requests

headers = {
    'domain-id': 'www',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'start-date': '2024-07-01',
    'end-date': '2024-08-31',
    'time-frame': 'Daily',
    'add-missing-rows': 'false',
}

url = 'https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/historical/39136'
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

data = response.json()
print(data)


The data you wanna get by defining from_date and to_date is not on the top page of the url https://www.investing.com/equities/aarons-historical-data you requested.
You have to make a request to https://api.investing.com/api/financialdata/historical/39136?start-date=2024-07-01&end-date=2024-08-31&time-frame=Daily&add-missing-rows=false, which is fired by a script on the top page.
The name 39136 in this API is the id of the stock you visit, which you can find it defined as instrument_id in the <script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json"> tag of the top page.

Dear vassiliev, have you tried it ?
This is the ouput of your url:
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2024 13:49:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 102
Connection: keep-alive
x-app-version: 1.82.0
x-correlation-id: ae17995d-57ca-424c-b71e-e82f9cfbb483
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Set-Cookie: .........
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 8c0fe1be3fa268ad-BUD
{"@errors":["Key: 'Request.Domain' Error:Field validation for 'Domain' failed on the 'required' tag"]}

Rather than using curl you might be better off using selenium to scrape the page you're interested in. Note that selenium is not part of the standard Python distribution so you may need to install it.
This seems to give what you need:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from urllib.parse import urlencode

TIMEOUT = 5
THS = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.freeze-column-w-1 thead tr th"
TDS = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.freeze-column-w-1 tbody tr td"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        url = "https://www.investing.com/equities/aarons-historical-data?"
        params = {
            "from_date": "07/01/2024",
            "to_date": "08/31/2024",
            "interval": "Daily",
        }
        driver.get(url + urlencode(params))
        output = []
        for th in WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(THS)):
            output.append(th.get_attribute("textContent"))
        ncols = len(output)
        for td in WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(TDS)):
            output.append(td.get_attribute("textContent"))
        for i in range(0, len(output), ncols):
            print(output[i : i + ncols])

Output:
['Date', 'Price', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Vol.', 'Change %']
['Sep 09, 2024', '10.07', '9.99', '10.07', '9.99', '744.79K', '+0.60%']
['Sep 06, 2024', '10.01', '10.02', '10.03', '9.98', '1.02M', '+0.20%']
['Sep 05, 2024', '9.99', '9.98', '10.00', '9.95', '1.51M', '+0.20%']
['Sep 04, 2024', '9.97', '9.95', '9.98', '9.94', '1.52M', '-0.10%']
['Sep 03, 2024', '9.98', '9.98', '10.08', '9.83', '5.17M', '-1.09%']
['Aug 30, 2024', '10.09', '10.09', '10.10', '10.09', '257.67K', '0.00%']
['Aug 29, 2024', '10.09', '10.10', '10.10', '10.09', '237.03K', '0.00%']
['Aug 28, 2024', '10.09', '10.09', '10.11', '10.08', '729.33K', '+0.20%']
['Aug 27, 2024', '10.07', '10.08', '10.09', '10.07', '313.87K', '-0.10%']
['Aug 26, 2024', '10.08', '10.09', '10.10', '10.08', '349.82K', '+0.10%']
['Aug 23, 2024', '10.07', '10.09', '10.11', '10.07', '879.99K', '0.00%']
['Aug 22, 2024', '10.07', '10.08', '10.10', '10.07', '599.27K', '-0.20%']
['Aug 21, 2024', '10.09', '10.09', '10.10', '10.08', '376.91K', '+0.10%']
['Aug 20, 2024', '10.08', '10.09', '10.09', '10.08', '484.85K', '0.00%']
['Aug 19, 2024', '10.08', '10.08', '10.10', '10.07', '1.04M', '+0.10%']
['Aug 16, 2024', '10.07', '10.08', '10.09', '10.07', '827.66K', '-0.10%']
['Aug 15, 2024', '10.08', '10.08', '10.09', '10.06', '776.58K', '+0.20%']
['Aug 14, 2024', '10.06', '10.08', '10.10', '10.06', '655.35K', '0.00%']
['Aug 13, 2024', '10.06', '10.04', '10.10', '10.04', '1.39M', '+0.50%']
['Aug 12, 2024', '10.01', '10.03', '10.04', '10.01', '463.42K', '-0.10%']

Note:
The usual way of getting an element's text is by accessing its .text attribute. However, due to timing issues around the rendering of the text (which I've discovered does happen on the site being scraped) you need to use the get_attribute("textContent") technique for a reliable result.

Like with my script, Youre output isn't corresponding the query data. That's the problem not the script ...

@MarcusAurelius The output from my answer is a precise representation of what's shown on the webpage. It's unclear to me what you were expecting otherwise

You see the params "from_date" and "to_date". That is what I expect. If You open the url in chrome you can change the dates from and to. I want to pass this by the parameters and catch these data.

@MarcusAurelius What made you think that passing query parameters would give you that result?

The curl scripts posted yesterday will do the job by adding the parametrs. Curl is tiny and  very fast while selenium is outdated
